# NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: object cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have a project the same menu as [this](http://code4app.net/ios/REFrostedViewController/525df2956803fab348000001)  but with submenu that the same slide animation. I create a xib file name it as SecondMenu.xib. The file owner is UIViewController and name it as SecondMenuController. If you check the project REFrosted ([check the link](http://code4app.net/ios/REFrostedViewController/525df2956803fab348000001)), there is DEMOMenuViewController(UIViewController). In method didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. I changed it in my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    SecondMenuController  *controller = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[SecondMenuController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondMenu" bundle:nil];
        [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:controller];

    }

    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }];

    //[self hideMenu];

}
```

That code work for me when connecting to submenu(which is SecondMenuController). In my SecondMenuController, I add a button (this will connect to DEMOHomeViewController, and the storyboard identifier is homeController). here's the code of my button

```
- (IBAction)buttonConnect:(id)sender {
    DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

    DEMOHomeViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[homeViewController];

    self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
    [self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```

I get this code in REFrosted before I changed it into my code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (as what I have mention above in first code). Why is it I get this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: object cannot be nil'
```

I import all files. As what I have understood, when you import a files that connect to the file owner. This means I have control for every method or function that inside of that file when you instantiate it into my SecondMenuController(this only based on my experienced, just rectify me if I'm wrong. I just want to know how the system work). Please see my code. Did I miss something here? Hoping for you advised on how can i fix this or explanation why I get this error.

```
    DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

    DEMOHomeViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[homeViewController];
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message? It says the `controller` is nil, have you verified that it is not nil? `NSLog()` for example? You need to debug your code.

Comment: Yes the homeViewController is nil. Why is it nil? the class is already connected to the board.

Comment: Time to debug. Check everything carefully, typos, class names, etc. Re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

2 days of searching an answer for this. I finally get it.

The reason why the DEMOHomeViewController is nil when I click the button because SecondMenuController didn't connect to DEMOHomeViewController even I instantiate it to SecondMenuController class. I learn now. Here's the code

first code that i do. I add this SecondMenuController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIStoryboard * myself;
@property (nonatomic, strong) REFrostedViewController * ref;   
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil myStoryBoard:(UIStoryboard *) xStoryBoard ref: (id) xRef;
```

In SecondMenuController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil myStoryBoard:(UIStoryboard *) xStoryBoard ref: (id) xRef
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.myself = xStoryBoard;
        self.ref = xRef;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my button

```
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [self.myself instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

DEMOSecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.myself instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];

navigationController.viewControllers = @[secondViewController];


self.ref.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
    [self.ref.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
```

Now it's working. All you need to do is to call the initWithNibName: method to the DEMOMenuViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The console log means you are attempting to insert nil object in NSArray, which is not allowed. If for some reason you need to add empty object use `(NSArray *)[NSNull null]` instead.

Comment: thanks russell. I already check it. The only code that i miss is, I didn't add connections between the two controllers.